# Is it legal to put a "CCTV in operation" sign outside my house if I don't actually have cctv? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom

As per title - I want to put off wrongdoers without having to go through the palaver of ensuring the camera is legal, so a sign about cctv but no actual camera. Is that legal in the UK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no law against lying, only lying to gain a commercial or illegal advantage. Go for it.

Comment: Also laws against lying under oath, and lying to impede certain government activities/investigations.